# Video driver not working after apt autoremove

Tags: nvidia, kernel, graphics

I had a failed update which caused kernel panics. I identified the problem as no remaining space in the boot partition, so I apt autoremoved to get rid of unused kernels and free up space, and then I updated and now I can boot.

But my nvidia driver doesn't work anymore. I have a laptop with an integrated AMD GPU and a discrete Nvidia GPU and only the AMD is working. I have tried:

```
sudo apt purge nvidia-driver*
sudo dpkg -P $(dpkg -l | grep nvidia-driver | awk '{print $2}')
sudo apt autoremove

reboot

sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

reboot
```

But that just gets me back to where I started, with non-functioning Nvidia drivers. The driver manager correctly identifies which driver I have installed, but the options are greyed out and it doesn't let me change anything.

I've gotten no meaningful error messages, at least not that I've noticed.

I did notice that one of the kernels which was removed was labeled as an nvidia kernel. There was also an oracle kernel and some others. This is a new laptop with a fresh Kubuntu install and has never had anything oracle on it.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured it out. Apparently the kernel headers were missing for the kernel that I'm using. I'm using 6.2.0-1009-lowlatency, so the solution was to run `apt install linux-headers-6.2.0-1009-lowlatency`.